# print certains columns by header name with spaces on it (awk,sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to extract certain columns from a file based on the header name. Some of the names have spaces (the file is tab-delimited). I cannot remove or substitute the spaces since downstream applications will be affected. What I am looking for is to extract some column based on header names and output them in the order I desire

Here is an example of my file:

```
 Sample Note Intragenic Rate ABCDE_177447
 1032 NA 0.97867626 0.9300704670625763 0.72782564
 ABCDE_177447 NA 0.97836965 1.0 0.87218356 
 ABCDE_188399 NA 0.97859967 0.905527730405171 0.81188565
 ABCDE_189595 NA 0.9787659 0.9059075892313707 0.8089241
 ABCDE_189596 NA 0.9788054 0.9065243881070291 0.8092951
```

My desired output;

```
 Sample Intragenic ABCDE_177447
 1032 0.97867626 0.9300704670625763 0.72782564
 ABCDE_177447 0.97836965 0.87218356 
 ABCDE_188399 0.97859967 0.81188565
 ABCDE_189595 0.9787659 0.8089241
 ABCDE_189596 0.9788054 0.8092951
```

I have tried this solution [AWK extract columns from file based on header selected from 2nd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098189/awk-extract-columns-from-file-based-on-header-selected-from-2nd-file?rq=1)

but it doesn't work with spaces on names and the same for this solution [Extracting columns from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605938/extracting-columns-from-a-file?lq=1)

I also have tried this

```
$cat cols.awk

BEGIN {
 n=split(cols,col)
 for (i=1; i<=n; i++) s[col[i]]=i
}
NR==1 {
 for (f=1; f<=NF; f++)
   if ($f in s) c[s[$f]]=f
 next
}
{ sep=""
 for (f=1; f<=n; f++) {
   printf("%c%s",sep,$c[f])
   sep=FS
 }
 print ""
}
```

But when I ran my script like `awk -F\t -f cols.awk.sh -v cols="Note,Sample,Intragenic Rate" metrics.txt` I got the following error:

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "1"
 input record number 2, file metrics.txt
 source line number 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v cols='Sample,Intragenic,ABCDE_177447' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; nc=split(cols, a, ",")} NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) hdr[$i]=i} {for (i=1; i<=nc; i++) if (a[i] in hdr) printf "%s%s", $hdr[a[i]], (i<nc?OFS:ORS)}' file

Sample  Intragenic  ABCDE_177447
1032    0.97867626  0.72782564
ABCDE_177447    0.97836965  0.87218356
ABCDE_188399    0.97859967  0.81188565
ABCDE_189595    0.9787659   0.8089241
ABCDE_189596    0.9788054   0.8092951
```

Using `cols` command line arguments you can pass a comma delimited list of columns to print.

Here is more readable awk:

```
awk -v cols='Sample,Intragenic,ABCDE_177447' 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
   nc=split(cols, a, ",")
}
NR==1 {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      hdr[$i]=i
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=nc; i++)
      if (a[i] in hdr)
         printf "%s%s", $hdr[a[i]], (i<nc?OFS:ORS)
}' file
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava, could you tell me how to do it for including command line arguments like yourfile.sh "cols1,cols 2" inputfile?

Comment: Inside `yourfile.sh` you can save this awk command: `awk -v cols="$1" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; nc=split(cols, a, ",")} NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) hdr[$i]=i} {for (i=1; i<=nc; i++) if (a[i] in hdr) printf "%s%s", $hdr[a[i]], (i<nc?OFS:ORS)}' "$2"` and then run it as `chmod +x yourfile.sh; ./yourfile.sh "cols1,cols 2" inputfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/Note Intragenic Rate/,"Intragenic")}{sub(/NA/, "")}NR>2{sub($3, "")}1' file

Sample Intragenic ABCDE_177447
1032  0.97867626 0.9300704670625763 0.72782564
ABCDE_177447  0.97836965  0.87218356 
ABCDE_188399  0.97859967  0.81188565
ABCDE_189595  0.9787659  0.8089241
ABCDE_189596  0.9788054  0.8092951
```