# building array with awk and/or shell

Tags: shell, awk

I used the following line to create an array of fields from a string:

```
var=$(echo $FieldName | awk -F";" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}')
```

`$FieldName` is a string having fields separated by semicolon.

When `$FieldName` contains string without whitespace it behaves properly.
The problem is when it contains any whitespace character embedded then the script treats the whitespace as newline.

e.g.:

```
$FieldName = aa;bcd;cal;da;ea;fa;ga;ha;ia
```

gives `[aa,bcd,cal,da,ea,fa,ga,ha,ia]` which is as expected.

But `$FieldName = aa;bcd;cal;da;ea;fa;ga;ha;ia <= ia2`

gives `[aa,bcd,cal,da,ea,fa,ga,ha,ia] , [<=, , , , , , , , ] and [ia2, , , , , , , , ]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the `$FieldName` in the `echo`?

Comment: that doesn't change anything. still the whitespace creates the same problem.

Comment: Like @chepner also implies, the fundamental problem is probably that you are using `echo $value` instead of `echo "$value"` with proper double quotes. Always quote your variable interpolations, unless you specifically require the shell to perform word splitting and wildcard expansion on the value.

Comment: I think the problem is what you do with `$var` -- what do you do with `$var`? Is `$var` quoted when you use it later in your script? Are you using `printf`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `awk`:

```
IFS=\;
set $FieldName
var=$@
```

Comment: Is `set -- $FieldName` any better?

Comment: this solution is more elegant but it still can't solve the problem created by the whitespace

Comment: @abhayK: `$9` will contain "ia <= ia2", whitespace and all. But when you expand the parameter, you need to quote it to protect that whitespace.

Comment: To join the string with `,` use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/bash-join-elements-of-an-array), i.e. `IFS=,` and `var="$*"`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to change the delimiter of `$FieldName`, in that case use `awk` like this:

```
echo "$FieldName" | awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=';' 1
```

The `1` executes the default block: `{ print $0 }`.

Or `tr`:

```
echo "$FieldName" | tr ';' ','
```

Output:

```
aa,bcd,cal,da,ea,fa,ga,ha,ia <= ia2
```