# Append to all elements of an array

Tags: arrays, shell, foreach

I was recently trying to created all unique path names, managed to get the unique names `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | sort -u` however I didn't really feel like appending the `export PATH = $PATH:` to them manually or through a for loop.

is there any way I can for that, something in the lines for

`'echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | sort -u | append each 'export PATH=\$PATH:'`

Comment: Your title implies that you want to append something to each element of `$PATH` but the question suggests that you want to modify `$PATH` so that it only contains unique entries.

Comment: Well that was the just one of the usecase. I've found myself doing this a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
path=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" " ")
append="something"
for p in $path; do s=$s$p$append":"; done
```

`$s` now contains your new path, with "something" appended to each element.

#### edit

you could use `printf` (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317171/2088135)):

```
append="something"
path=($(echo $PATH | tr ":" " ")) # notice the additional parentheses
printf "%s$append:" "${path[@]}"
```

not really shorter but maybe a bit fancier!

Comment: that's what I ended up doing but was wondering it there's a shorter way

Comment: @RishiB I've added another option

Comment: Thanks, printf did it. Used it in another way ...

`printf "export PATH=\$PATH:%s\n" $(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | sort -u)`

Gives you everything in nice pretty lines