# Pass a variable number of bash command line arguments to a MATLAB function

Tags: bash, matlab, unix, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

Arguments that are passed to a bash script can be passed on to a MATLAB function in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "my_function('$1','$2')"
```

But how to do this if I do not know the number of arguments to pass a priori? So I want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "my_function('$1',...,'$N')"
```

where I do not know what number N equals to a priori.

I figure that you could create a string with a for loop containing `'$1',...,'$N'` and pass the entire string to the above command. But isn't there a more succinct approach?

FIW, I am not fluent in bash. So if the loop is the only way to go, could you please inform me how to do this?

**EDIT**

I managed to devise a solution to my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=""
for var in "$@"
do
    INPUT=$INPUT"'"$var"',"
done
INPUT=${INPUT%?}

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "my_function($INPUT)"
```

Isn't there a easier/shorter way to do this?

Comment: At what point of time you would know the value of N ?

Comment: Never. The thing is that I am developing a program in MATLAB. The number of input arguments to the main MATLAB function might change over time. And I do not want to modify my bash script that launches my MATLAB program each time I decide to add another input argument.

Comment: +1 for the correct spelling - `MATLAB` instead of `matlab` which is widely used around here on Stack Overflow. Sorry, no useful comment from me though.

Answer (score 3):

Taking inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883271/1563512):

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$(printf "'%s'," "$@") && INPUT=${INPUT%,}

echo matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "my_function($INPUT)"
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh one two three
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r my_function('one','two','three')
```

It's a little shorter, at least.