# bash ~ How to search through files in a directory

Tags: regex, bash

I have a list of files

- shopping-list.txt
- our-shopping-list.txt
- test.txt
- my-test.txt

I want to run `myscript shopping` and get the two files that have the word `shopping`. I want to run `myscript our list` and get just the one file.

at the moment I have this

```
if [[ $fs =~ .*${*}*.* ]]; then
        echo $fs
fi
```

It works a bit, but it would not give me `our-shopping-list` if each variable has a gap ie. `myscript our list` it would work if I typed `myscript our - list`

I have a big list of files and want to find the one I need by guessing the name

---

my attempt to apply @pacholik's code

```
snippetdir="~/my_snippets/"
    for filename in $snippetdir*; do
        file=`basename "$filename"`
        fs=${file%.*}
        for i in ${*}; do
    for j in *${i}*; do
        if [[ $fs =~ .*$j*.* ]]; then
                echo $fs
            fi      
        done
        done
    done
```

Comment: may I know what this `${*}` does?

Comment: What's wrong with `ls *'shopping'*`?

Comment: kiss `if [[ $fs =~ shopping ]]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `${*}` means any variable.Your if statement results in same problems

Comment: @choroba that's the same thing as `*${*}*`

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want to search if the user specifies several parameters?

Comment: @choroba sorry, words, like my example works if I search `shopping` but not if I search `our list`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple brute-force loop.

```
for file in *; do
    t=true
    for word in "$@"; do
        case $file in
          *"$word"*) ;; 
          *) t=false; break;;
        esac
    done
    $t && echo "$file"
done
```

I believe this should be portable to any POSIX shell, and potentially beyond (old Solaris etc).

Answer (score -1):

Using just bash expansion (only you have to evaluate twice). Bash join from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/bash-join-elements-of-an-array).

```
files=`IFS=* eval 'echo *"${*}"*'`
```

Then you can iterate over `$files`

```
for i in $files; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks @pacholik I don't seem to know how to incorporate that to my code, Can you check the code I added in my answer?

Comment: @relidon: Edited. I've misunderstood it before.