# Appending a character to every element except the last one of a bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I am looking to append each element of a bash array with `|` except the last one.

```
array=("element1" "element2" "element3")
```

My desired output would be

```
array=("element1"|"element2"|"element3")
```

What I have done

```
for i in ${!array[@]}; 
do
array1+=( "${array[$i]}|" )
done
```

Followed by

```
array=echo ${array1[@]}|sed 's/|$//'
```

Is there any other looping approach I can use that only appends the character until the last but one element?

Comment: `array=("element1"|"element2"|"element3")` is just one element instead of 3, is that you want?

Comment: @anubhava, yes just one element is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your special case, where only **one single character has to be inserted between each array member**, the simplest solution is probably to **use array expansion** (and changing the separation character `IFS` according to your need beforehand):

```
$ array=("element1" "element2" "element3")
$ array=( $( IFS="|" ; echo "${array[*]}") )
$ echo "\$array[0] is '${array[0]}'"
$array[0] is 'element1|element2|element3'
```

Comment: This reduces the question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/bash-join-elements-of-an-array), but OP seems to want an array with a single element - which is easily done, though, by using `array=($( IFS="|" ; echo "${array[*]}"))`. The command substitution neatly confines the `IFS` change to a subshell, so +1 :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. I didn't see the point to create a single-member array, but this is of course what has been asked for. I updated my response accordingly, so the output data type is "array" : )

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# append | all except last element
read -ra array < <( printf "%s|" "${array[@]:0:$((${#array[@]} - 1))}"; echo "${array[@]: -1}"; )

# Check array content now
declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="element1|element2|element3")'
```

- `"${array[@]:0:$((${#array[@]} - 1))}"` will get all but last element of array
- `"${array[@]: -1}"` will get the last element of array
- `printf "%s|"` will append `|` in front of all the arguments
- `< <(...)` is process substitution to read output of any command from stdin
- `read -ra` will read the input in an array

Comment: Thanks very much @anubhava. Precisely what I wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

```
$ array=("element1" "element2" "element3")
$ printf -v str "|%s" "${array[@]}"
$ array=("${str:1}")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="element1|element2|element3")'
```

The `printf` statement creates a string `str` that contains `|element1|element2|element3`, i.e., one more `|` than we want (at the beginning).

The next statement uses substring parameter expansion, `${str:1}`, to skip the first character and reassigns to `array`, which now consists of a single element.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution (if you don't mind changing IFS) is:

```
$ array=("element1" "element2" "element3")
$ IFS="|"; printf "%s\n" "${array[*]}"
```

And to re-assign to the variable array (which doesn't change IFS):

```
$ array=("$(IFS="|"; printf "%s\n" "${array[*]}")")
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
element1|element2|element3
```

An alternative solution is:

```
$ array=($(printf '%s|' "${array[@]}")); array="${array%?}"
$ printf '%s\n' "${array}"
```

A more complex solution (script) is:

```
array=("element1" "element2" "element3")

       delimiter='|'
       unset newarr
for    val in "${array[@]}"
do     newarr=$newarr${newarr+"$delimiter"}$val
done

array=("$newarr")

echo "array=($array)"
```