# reformatting text file from rows to column

Tags: bash, shell, centos7

i have multiple files in a directory that i need to reformat and put the output in one file, the file structure is:

```
========================================================
Daily KPIs  -   DATE:  24/04/2013
========================================================

--------------------------------------------------------
Number of des         =  5270
--------------------------------------------------------
Number of users       =  210
--------------------------------------------------------
Number of active      =  520
--------------------------------------------------------
Total non             =  713
--------------------------------------------------------

========================================================
```

I need the output format to be:

```
Date,Numberofdes,Numberofusers,Numberofactive,Totalnon
24042013,5270,210,520,713
```

The directory has around 1500 files with the same format and im using Centos 7.

Thanks

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: hi Cyrus, this is what I've reached so far:  cat file.txt |sed 's/ //g'|sed 's/-//g'|sed 's/========================================================//g'|awk -F'[=;]' '{print $2}'|sed '/^$/d'|tr "/n" ",".. my output is 1128,718,7308,9154, im unable to get the dates on the column..

Comment: Please add this to your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need a method to join the elements of an array into a string (*cf.* [Join elements of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/bash-join-elements-of-an-array)):

```
function join_array()
{
    local IFS=$1
    shift
    echo "$*"
}
```

Then we can cycle over each of the files and convert each one into a comma-separated list (assuming that the original file have a name ending in `*.txt`).

```
for f in *.txt
do
    sed -n 's/[^:=]\+[:=] *\(.*\)/\1/p' < $f | {
        mapfile -t fields
        join_array , "${fields[@]}"
    }
done
```

Here, the `sed` command looks inside each input file for lines that:

1. begin with a substring that contains neither a `:` nor a `=` character (the `[^:=]\+` part);
2. then follow a `:` or a `=` and an arbitrary number of spaces (the `[:=] *` part);
3. finally, end with an arbitrary substring (the `*\(.*\)` part).

The last substring is then captured and printed instead of the original string.  Any other line in the input files is discared.

After that, the output of `sed` is read by `mapfile` into the indexed array variable `fields` (the `-t` ensures that trailing newlines from each line read are discarded) and finally the lines are joined thanks to our previously-defined `join_array` method.

The reason whereby we need to wrap `mapfile` inside a subshell is explained here: [readarray (or pipe) issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/readarray-or-pipe-issue).

Comment: Woot, you hit #1 on the [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) list.

Comment: @ghoti, fixed it!  Thank you.

Comment: wow, this works perfectly, the only thing im missing are the header, any way to include it? can you please explain the solution aswll?.. thanks

Comment: @RobertoReale Hi Roberto, i'm currently facing an issue when i moved it into production server which is solaris 10, whever i issue the above command, the output is just an empty lines, any idea why is that?

Comment: @AliJaber, are you sure you are using Bash on Solaris?

Comment: @RobertoReale, I was using an old bash version, i've updated it to 4.3 and its working fine now, thank you..