# How to use LS command with array in bash

Tags: bash

```
declare -a list=(data backups dailystatus inbound reports )

ls ${list[0]}/${list[1]}/${list[2]}/${list[3]}/${list[4]}/
```

I need to check daily backups are working or not similar this I have 2 more locations for checking backup. Can someone help me to find out the better way than this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Why are you storing the path components as separate array elements, instead of a single directory path?

Comment: It might be a start to describe *why* your current approach is inadequate, how it fails, how to reproduce that failure, and how a potential solution should be evaluated for correctness. (A better explanation of why you're writing code like this in the first place would help too; in general, [programmatic use of `ls` is error-prone, and consequently frowned on](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: ...that said, generally, one would store one path to an array element: `list=( /data/backups/{daily,weekly,monthly}status/inbound/reports )`, for instance, will give you an array with one dailystatus path, one weeklystatus path, and one monthly status path -- much more sensible than splitting the path elements into an array element per each for no obvious reason (and if you *have* a reason, **include it in the question!**).

Answer (score 0):

from [Join elements of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/bash-join-elements-of-an-array)

```
#!/bin/bash
list=(data backups dailystatus inbound reports )
bar=$(printf "/%s" "${list[@]}")
echo $bar
```

Answer (score -1):

One way(assuming you do not have any multi worded directory):

```
x=${list[@]}
ls ${x// /\/}
```

Concatenate all array elements into variable `x` and then replace the space with a `/`

Comment: This fails if a directory has a space in its name.

Comment: @chepner : that was precisely what I had mentioned in brackets

Comment: Why would you give an answer you know is buggy (doesn't cover the entire input domain -- that input domain, in this case, being "possible filenames on UNIX") when you could fix it instead, and give an answer that's correct?