# LS two folder side by side

Tags: bash, paste, ls

How do I paste the content of two folders side by side so that output looks like

```
some_command dir1 dir2

dir1_file1 dir2_file1
dir1_file2 dir2_file2
dir1_file3 dir2_file3
dir1_file4 dir2_file4
```

Comment: do the files have same names across 2 directories?

Comment: In my specific case they have some similarities but they are not really the same.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look in gnu `diff` utility combined with process substitution:

```
$ diff -y <(ls ./tmp) <(ls ./tmp2)
20161201.csv                              <
20161202.csv                              <
aa.txt                              aa.txt
a.txt                               a.txt
bb.txt                              bb.txt
bsd.bsd                             bsd.bsd
b.txt                               b.txt

$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(ls ./tmp) <(ls ./tmp2)
20161201.csv                              <
20161202.csv                              <
```

See `man diff` for more options.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 3 commands:

```
ls -1 dir1 > file1
ls -1 dir2 > file2
pr -m -t file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sdiff` and view the 2 directories side by side like so:

```
$ sdiff <(ls -1 dir1) <(ls -1 dir2)
```

Any differences between the 2 directories will be reflected with a `<` or `>` depending on which side of the comparison is missing a specific file/sub-directory.

#### Example

```
$ sdiff <(ls -1 dir1) <(ls -1 dir2)
alison_krauss                                                   alison_krauss
Bach - Brandenburg Concertos                                  <
band_of_horses                                                  band_of_horses
Barenaked Ladies                                              <
big_star                                                        big_star
bob_seger                                                       bob_seger
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for the *hack* of diffing / sdiffing this. This introduces useless processing. The same for `pr`.

If all you need is to print files from two folders side-by-side, all you need is `paste`. This command is precisely for not counting, not diffing, but simply printing multiple files side-by-side in (by default) tab-separated fields, one line per file.

Just do:

```bash
paste <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
```

You can easily make this into a script or a function.

## 6 Excellent Free Books to Learn Bash

1. [GNU Bash Reference Manual by Chet Ramey, Brian Fox](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)
2. [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide by Mendel Cooper](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)
3. [The Linux Command Line by William Shotts](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)
4. [Bash Guide for Beginners by Machtelt Garrels](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)
5. [The Bash Guide by Maarten Billemont](https://guide.bash.academy/)
6. [Linux Shell Scripting Tutorial by Vivek Gite](https://www.linuxlinks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Linux_shell_scripting_v2.pdf)

#1 is authored by Chet Ramey, the author of `bash`.

I had at some point a book exclusively dedicated to shell filters, but that was in the early 90s, before bash, Linux, electricity...

## EDIT

Here's the function:

```bash
function join_by {
  local d=${1-} f=${2-}
  if shift 2; then
    printf %s "$f" "${@/#/$d}"
  fi
}

sbs() {
  d="<(ls `join_by ') <(ls ' $*`)"
  echo $d
  eval paste $d
}
```

The auxiliary function `join_by` was contributed [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841619/2571805) almost a decade ago, because bash, just like diamonds, is forever.