# Bash script with variable from a different file in array

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I have a `config.txt` file with the following:

```
VAR=('a' 'b' 'c')
database='mydb'
```

and I want to use the `VAR` variable in the script (`myscript.sh`) to check if any of the data in it exists in a search that will be made on the database.

The search I am doing is like this:

```
output=$(mysql $database -u $user -p$pass -se "select name from my_table where word = '$VAR'")
```

Comment: You define `VAR` as an array but use it as a "scalar". What actual value are you wanting to use in that select statement? Do you want to iterate over the array?

Comment: I want to search the database for each one of the data stored in the variable VAR. One of them should return a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @Olli's answer:

```
source config.txt

# SQL injection
# values=$(printf "'%s'\n" "${VAR[@]}" | paste -sd,)
values=$(printf "'%s'\n" "${VAR[@]//\'/\'\'}" | paste -sd,)

select="select name from my_table where word in ($values)"
output=$(mysql "$database" -u "$user" -p"$pass" -se "$select")
```

Comment: each time i use source in the script i get:
line 19: mysql: command not found
line 21: ls: command not found

Comment: that sounds like you need to ask a separate question, and you have to show the code.

Comment: I created a script to test your solution, the only thing i have more is at the beginning the #!/bin/sh, the rest is the same as you wrote above. i got GNU is because of that?

Comment: Because of what? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can read files into your script with the [source](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) command (aliased simply as `.`) like so:

```
. config.txt
# or
source config.txt
```

To get a comma separated string, check for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/join-elements-of-an-array)

Comment: That won't quite work; it doesn't appear from its use that `VAR` is supposed to be a shell array.

Comment: VAR is supposed to have more than one data, therefore an array, and i want to use it to search the database for each one of them. How can i do that?