# Concat array elements with comma and single quote - Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

How to convert array elements with single quotes and comma in Bash.

```
arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")
#element1 element2 element3
```

**Desired result**
`'element1','element2','element3'`

From [Martin Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527146/5811973) answer comma seprated values are achieved using [IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184867/247144),

```
SAVE_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=","
ARRJOIN="${arr[*]}"
IFS="$SAVE_IFS"

echo "$ARRJOIN"
#element1,element2,element3
```

But how to add single quotes to each element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ joined=$(printf ",'%s'" "${arr[@]}")
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ echo ${joined:1}
'element1','element2','element3'
```

Comment: Why ${joined:1} and not simply ${joined}? Or: what does the :1 do?

Comment: Ah, it removes the first character. And the join of course produces a extra comma at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Just use sed:

```
sed -E "s/([[:alnum:]]+)/'&'/g;s/ /,/g" <<< ${arr[@]}
```

One the first sed command, surround all alpha numeric strings with single quotes and on the second command, replace the spaces with commas.

Comment: This won't work right if any elements contain non-alphanumeric characters (spaces, punctuation, etc).