# Take multiple (any number of input) input strings and concatenate in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I want to input multiple strings.

For example:

```
abc
xyz
pqr
```

and I want output like this (including quotes) in a file:

```
"abc","xyz","pqr"
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't give the expected output.

```
NextEmail=","
until [ "a$NextEmail" = "a" ];do
   echo "Enter next E-mail: "
   read NextEmail
   Emails="\"$Emails\",\"$NextEmail\""
done
echo -e $Emails
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

# via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/join-elements-of-an-array
function join_by { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

emails=()
while read line
do
    if [[ -z $line ]]; then break; fi
    emails+=("$line")
done

join_by ',' "${emails[@]}"
```

---

```
$ bash vvuv.sh
my-email
another-email
third-email

my-email,another-email,third-email
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Actually, I want to retain quotes.

"my-email","another-email","third-email"

Comment: You could change the last line to `join_by '","' "\"${emails[@]}\""` for the quotes, and the while loop could be (Bash 4.0 or newer) `readarray -t emails < /dev/stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed and `paste`:

```
sed 's/.*/"&"/' infile | paste -sd,
```

The sed command puts `""` around each line; `paste` does serial pasting (`-s`) and uses `,` as the delimiter (`-d,`).

If input is from standard input (and not a file), you can just remove the input filename (`infile`) from the command; to store in a file, add a redirection at the end (`> outfile`).

Answer (score 0):

If you can withstand a trailing comma, then `printf` can convert an array, with no loop required...

```
$ readarray -t a < <(printf 'abc\nxyx\npqr\n' )
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="abc" [1]="xyx" [2]="pqr")
$ printf '"%s",' "${a[@]}"; echo
"abc","xyx","pqr",
```

(To be fair, there's a loop running inside bash, to step through the array, but it's written in C, not bash. :) )

If you wanted, you could replace the final line with:

```
$ printf -v s '"%s",' "${a[@]}"
$ s="${s%,}"
$ echo "$s"
"abc","xyx","pqr"
```

This uses `printf -v` to store the imploded text into a variable, `$s`, which you can then strip the trailing comma off using Parameter Expansion.