# Set output delimiter for printing directory content

Tags: bash

I would like to print content of directory separated by specific delimiter (in my case ':').
So I am searching for equivalent of this loop:

```
for f in * ; do printf $f: ; done
```

But this loop print extra ':' at the end and I am pretty sure there is more elegant solution for my case. I tried something like

```
echo * | tr " " :
```

But there is a problem if filename contains spaces. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When wrapped in double quotes, `$*` expands to a list of positional parameters separated with the first character of `IFS`. So, here you go:

```
( set -- * ; IFS=':' ; printf '%s\n' "$*" )
```

Comment: Nice! U could replace `printf '%s\n'` by simply `echo`.

Comment: @F.Hauri Nah, echo is not reliable. See [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: ?? `(set -- *;IFS=:;echo "$*")` work fine and to set a variable: `dirColon=$(set -- *;IFS=:;echo "$*")`! What do you mean by *not reliable*? (Note: quotes on colons in `IFS=` declaration are useless)

Comment: Follow the link I added to my comment. I really don't have time for giving a lecture about it. And quotes in variable assignment is a matter of taste; I like it that way

Comment: Its great command oguz, but two things are not clear for me:
1) Why double dash in set? I know what is general meaning of double dash, but can't find example why could I need it here.
2) Couldn't the last part be just printf "$*"? Do we need the string format part?

Comment: @oguzismail I just noticed it doesn't solve my problem - I wanted to set PYTHONPATH via this command, but when I write export PYTHONPATH=$(your command) it has no colons ;/

Comment: @user3361462 `export PYTHONPATH=$(set -- *;IFS=':';printf '%s\n' "$*")` works fine here. Wrt *why double dash?*; to tell `set` no further options are given on the command line. And *do we need the format part?* yes, otherwise a filename containing `%` would break it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in * ; do printf $f: ; done | sed 's/.$//'
```

Will do the trick

Also here is another option: [How can I join elements of an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/how-can-i-join-elements-of-an-array-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the trailing `:` with `sed`:

```
for f in * ; do printf $f: ; done | sed 's/:$//'
```

But the `printf %f` will fail if filename has for example `%s` or `%d` or `%f` or `%c` or space or tab in the filename. It's better to quote your variables and do:

```
for f in * ; do printf "%s:" "$f"; done | sed 's/:$//'
```

Or just:

```
printf "%s:" * | sed 's/:$//'
```

If filenames do not have newlines, you could print them with newlines and join using `paste`:

```
printf "%s\n" * | paste -sd:
```

Or you could use `IFS` with `$*` expansion to join the output, with additional function:

```
f() { ( IFS=:; printf "%s" "$*"; ); }; f *
```