# Can't substitute white spaces characters in string with parameter expansion

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I want to join array elements by using parameter expansion syntax on them and expect following code to work:

```
declare -a nums=( {1..10} )
echo ${nums[@]// /,}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#but
echo ${nums[@]//1/,}
, 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Can I make substitution work on white spaces?

Comment: You can apply PE to individual elements of the array (because they are treated as strings), but _not_ the content of the array as a whole

Comment: See [How can I join elements of an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527049/5291015)

Answer (score 4):

`${nums[@]}"` is not a string but an array of 10 numbers which is the reason that substituting space with comma doesn't work as there is no space in array.

You can get array content in a string and do string replacement:

```
declare -a nums=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 )
s="${nums[*]}"
echo "${s// /,}"
```

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Or one liner:

```
IFS=, && printf '%s\n' "${nums[*]}" && unset IFS
```

Comment: Nice! I really like the oneliner. Would `echo "${nums[*]}"` be equivalent to the `printf` version or is there some corner case that could mess that up?

Comment: No there is no corner case as far as I know