# Converting bash array into string with - in between

Tags: arrays, bash

How do I convert an array into a string with a dash '-' in between in bash. For eg, I have this array

```
arr=(a b c d e)
```

I want to convert it into a string "a-b-c-d".
I figured out this "a-b-c-d-e," but there is an unwanted dash at the end. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: See: [How can I join elements of an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527049/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

This is where the `"${arr[*]}"` expansion form is useful (note the double quotes and the `*` index). This joins the array elements using the first character of the `IFS` variable

```bash
arr=(a b c d e)

joined=$(IFS='-'; echo "${arr[*]}")
declare -p joined
# => declare -- joined="a-b-c-d-e"
```

But if you want all-but-the-last elements, you'll combine this with the `${var:offset:length}` expansion

```bash
joined=$(IFS='-'; echo "${arr[*]:0: ${#arr[@]} - 1}")
declare -p joined
# => declare -- joined="a-b-c-d"
```

This one's a little tricker. The `offset` and `length` parts of that expansion are arithmetic expressions. I'm calculating the length as "the number of elements in the array minus one".

Note how I'm defining `IFS` inside the command substitution parentheses: this is overriding the variable *in the subshell* of the command substitution, so it won't affect the IFS variable in your *current* shell.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` if you want to remove the last entry

```
$ awk -vOFS=- '{NF--;$1=$1}1' <<<${arr[@]}
a-b-c-d
```

or the complete array

```
$ awk -vOFS=- '{$1=$1}1' <<<${arr[@]}
a-b-c-d-e
```